# double click on datagrid view to open email messages

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

this is for winforms using c#
I have a datagridview which lists the email messages (.msg) in a folder.

my aim: if user double clicks on a cell in the datagridview, the corresponding email message must be opened for view

how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be storing the path of the `msg` file some where right? Then you can use the `CellDoubleClick` or the `CellMouseDoubleClick` event to open the msg file using [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx). I assume outlook is installed and MSG file is associated with outlook. Hope this gives enough information **write you own code**.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out which row is selected first, then obtain the cell where it is actually selected and intercept the datagridview mouse event handler (doubleclick) to trigger the load of the message.
As an example


`private void dataGridView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

 // Check if the selected cell count is 1 only

  if (this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells.Count == 1)

  {

   DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection col = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells;

   // Example: The column of a selected row contains the value Msg

   if (col[0].Value == "Msg")

    {

     // Trigger the load mechanism

    }

  }

        }`

Hope this gives you the right direction,
Best regards,
Tom.